# Hide scroll bar in Gantt chart

Tags: jquery, gantt

I want to hide the horizontal scroll bar on the lefthand side pane of a standard Sharepoint Gantt view.

This site shows how to do it for the whole chart

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ec27efe3-8109-48fe-9d50-35590fb873cf/removing-scrollbars-from-project-tasks?forum=sharepointadminlegacy

That stops scroll bars on both left and right hand sides.

I've tried the following jqueries

```
$([id$='_ListViewWebPartJSGrid_leftpane'],'.scroll-bar-outer-box').css({'overflow':'hidden !important','position':'static','height':'auto'});
$([id$='_ListViewWebPartJSGrid_leftpane'],'.horiz-scroll-bar-outer-box').css({'overflow':'hidden !important', 'position':'static','height':'auto'});
$([id$='_ListViewWebPartJSGrid_leftpane'],'.ms-ganttDiv').css({'overflow':'hidden !important', 'position':'static','height':'auto'});
```

But none of these selectors seem to hit the mark.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one here:

```
$("div[id$='_ListViewWebPartJSGrid_leftpane'] .outer-scroll-bar").hide()
```